# Python TypeError: 'TagList' object is not iterable

Tags: python, gstreamer

This happens all the time. A function returns an object that I can't read. Here:

```
    discoverer = GstPbutils.Discoverer()
    discoverer.connect('discovered', on_discovered)
    info = discoverer.discover_uri(self.loaded_file)
    print(vinfo.get_tags())
```

Returns this:

```
<Gst.TagList object at 0x7f00a360c0a8 (GstTagList at 0x7f00880024a0)>
```

But when I try to do this:

```
    tags = vinfo.get_tags()
    for tag in tags:
        print (tag)
```

I get this:

```
TypeError: 'TagList' object is not iterable
```

But when I read [the doc of this data structure](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gst-1.0/structs/TagList.html#Gst.TagList), I seem to understand it's ... List? Can somebody, beyond telling me how to get the tags, indicate me *how to read* those docs? Also, am I missing some introspection methods and tools, that I could use to discover what the objects I encounter are, and how they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all hypothetical as I never used python with GStreamer:

According to documentation - yes it is said its list.. but this could be represented as internal structure.. remember that python bindings are just.. bindings - it all works similarly (if not implemented in a better way) as in C.. and what do you do in [C with tags to iterate them](https://developer.gnome.org/gstreamer/stable/gstreamer-GstTagList.html#gst-tag-list-foreach) .. but dont ask me how I found it out - you have to look around the docs checking all available functions.

You have to be wise and think of how could the object you are using may be implemented - along with the fact you know what it represents.. I mean - this is the list of tags when each tag has different type - one is string, the other one is int etc.. you cannot easily iterate over that.

So I think you have two options - according to what do you want to do with the tags..

1, serialize to string and work with that:

I am not sure but in C there is [to_string](https://developer.gnome.org/gstreamer/stable/gstreamer-GstTagList.html#gst-tag-list-to-string) which may do the same thing as in [to_string](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gst-1.0/structs/TagList.html#Gst.TagList.to_string) in python - so try that if you are interested only in the tag names.. or whatever it returns.

2, use builtin [foreach](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gst-1.0/structs/TagList.html#Gst.TagList.foreach) with its callback definition:

```
 tags = vinfo.get_tags()
 tags.foreach(my_callback, self)
```

And in your callback:

```
 def my_callback(list, tag, user_data):
   print(tag)
   #do whatever you want with list
   #not sure how to use casting in python:
   YourClass ptr = user_data
   ptr.your_method(whatever, tag);
```